# Alarmmanager not working with large seconds

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have made simple alarm by alarm-manager the problem is when insert many seconds it is not working in time which i declared here

this is code

```
 mo = ((Integer.parseInt(mons.getText().toString())) * (30 * 24 * 60 * 60));
         we = ((Integer.parseInt(weeks.getText().toString())) * (7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
         da = ((Integer.parseInt(days.getText().toString())) * (24 * 60 * 60));
         ho = ((Integer.parseInt(hours.getText().toString())) * (60 * 60));
         mi = ((Integer.parseInt(mins.getText().toString())) * (60));

         int all = mo+we+da+ho+mi;



       Intent i = new Intent(Messages.this, Alarm.class);
       PendingIntent pd = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 5484, i, 0);
       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (all*1000), pd);
```

and this is Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"ALarm....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showNotification( context);
}
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"M_CH_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setContentTitle("فكرنى")
                .setContentText("I think you need to do something")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);      
    NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager =
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: what does it do (wrong)? do you get an error message?

Comment: there isnot any message and it run but alarm not work in time @Stultuske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it gets "wrong" around 828 seconds (± 2 seconds, I'm lazy to do an MWE), then you have a simple integer-overflow when calculating `mo`, cf. https://dzone.com/articles/overflow-and-underflow-data

Use `long`s or do your calculation otherwise (based on some date-objects?).

Edit: I need more coffee, of course you won't get it around 828 seconds, as seconds aren't passed to the month evaluation. I am still betting on an integer-ovewflow though, just not exactly with this value and variable.

Comment: I feel obliged to warn you, that with `long` you will still get an overflow eventually, just for bigger numbers, i.e., just using `long` is not a bullet-proof solution.

If you feel so, please accept my answer, so other SO users see your question as answered.

Comment: @AhmedElBagory no, you didn't accept it yet, "just" upvoted it ;) Click on the checkmark next to the answer, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @D.Kovács `long` is fine; OP will *not* get an overflow with `long`s - unless he schedules the alarm some 300 **billion** years into the future.

Comment: @JimmyB you are, of course, right, if I see it correctly the earliest overflow will be with `mi` at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2**63-1%2F1000%2F60+seconds which is almost exactly 300 billion years, kudos!